# What is an appropriate way to address this problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, python, natural-language

I have the following problem:

Given long texts (around 15K words each), and five values associated with each one of them (the famous big5 traits), predict, for a new text, its big5 values based on the available training data.

An example training row looks like this:

```
big5_openness | big5_conscientiousness | big5_extraversion | big5_agreeableness | big5_neuroticism | input_text
```

Each big5 value is an integer between 0 and 100. Assume the input_text is in english, but it contains many weird symbols (codes for emojis, for example)

My idea is the following:

1. Use a sentence encoder to transform each text into a vector.
2. This becomes a regression problem - fit the encoded texts (vectors, that are represented as a matrix `X`) and the y values (these are the big5 values, that are of shape `(1, 5)`) into a regressor and predict for new input.

The limitations:

1. The texts are huge - I am using `bert` to encode sentences (https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens), but it considers only the first 500 tokens, which is not sophisticated enough. I have tried `Longformer`, but it is extremely slow and it also has token limitation: 4096.
2. Predict all 5 values at the same time - I am using `xgb.XGBRegressor` to predict only 1 value at a time. I would like to use some model that can predict all values at once (because there could be a correlation between them and it would probably be more accurate if the model predicts them at once)

I have implemented my ideas and, using RMSE as error metric, I have average 21 error (RMSE) for predicting only the first big5 value: openness.
Dimensions of my input:

```
X_train: (16378, 768)
y_train: (16378,)
X_validate: (1820, 768)
y_validate: (1820,)
```

NOTE! The y-s only contain one value, because I am running only on the first big5 value.

Do you have any ideas how to approach this problem to achieve better accuracy, speed, what would be a good structure of the whole pipeline to approach this problem?

Comment: It seems like the main challenge you're facing is how to make 5 predictions. You could make 5 gradient boosted models, one for each prediction, but that's probably slow to train and cumbersome to maintain. A neural network with 5 output nodes seems like a promising step. BERT and other sesame street models are state-of-the-art on certain tasks, but a cheap and fast way to make a model that suits this purpose is to just use a bag-of-words/TF-IDF approach, maybe with some refinements from there. It might not be as good as BERT (you'd have to do the experiment to find out), but it will be easier.

Comment: Sycorax, thank you for your answer, I appreciate it! Yes, exactly, my main purpose is to to make 5 predictions (at once). I was thinking about neural network, but I am not sure if I can have a network (such that each output node predicts a class (from 100 classess)). I am also not sure how to model such a neural network (hyperparameters and description of layers). If you could guide me by some links, I would be really grateful! :)

Comment: Why are there 100 classes? I thought the five OCEAN attributes were measured on a 0 to 100 scale? We have lots of discussion about how to choose different configurations of a NN, which you can find using search. Here's a search to get you started: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+choose++%5Bneural-networks%5D+answers%3A1+score%3A1 and some tips on how to use search https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/faq-best-practices-for-searching-cv

Comment: Yes, exactly. the five OCEAN attributes have from 0-100 values. Can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes, in the simplest case, that's just a multivariate regression.